# Listen in to data read from file descriptor to ttyS

Tags: tty, serial-port, file-descriptors

I have a serial device under /dev/ttyS0 and an application that is reading from the serial device (but not writing to it).  I wanted to listen in to the data that is coming in on the serial device but I believe the cat /dev/ttyS0 won't work becuase it is already opened by the application.

I can find the file descriptor in /proc/pid##/fd to /dev/ttyS0.  Is there a way to tap into the data coming in on the serial line?  I have root access if needed.  I don't have the ability to modify the application.

Comment: You might be able to `strace` the program and just look at the `read()` calls